# How to ignore namespaces during xsl translation time

Tags: xslt

I have an xml as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books xmlns="http://www.books.com/SRK">
    <name>English</name>
</books
```

I required the following output after translation using xsl .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
    <name>English</name>
</books>
```

I need an xsl to ignore the namespace.I have tried something but its not working with namespace.

I need your help.Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  When posting code, please indent 4 spaces or use the `{}` button in the editor so it will display correctly.  I fixed it for you.

Comment: Can you post a more complex sample of your input?

Answer (score 6):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(self::*)]">
  <xsl:copy/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<books xmlns="http://www.books.com/SRK">
    <name>English</name>
</books>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<books>
   <name>English</name>
</books>
```

Comment: Can you explain the needing of `[not(self::*)]`. I've tested without it and it works as well. (+1)

Comment: It seems also that only the second template is necessary. Am I right?

Comment: @empo: For this specific XML document just the second template produces the wanted result. However, an XML document typically has: attributes, comment-nodes, PI-nodes. My solution works with any XML document that has any mixture of these kinds of nodes.

Comment: Its working only if i include the above templates if i add some other templates other than the above one then the translation is not at all working .None of the template getting executed.

Comment: @malledugu: in order to use these templates in context, you need to understand how the XSLT processing model works, i.e., how XSLT decides what templates to apply, to what nodes. See e.g. http://www.soe.ucsc.edu/classes/cmps183/Spring06/lectures/XSLT-language-processing.pdf

Comment: @malledugu: This is the same with any source code -- if you add your own code to it then it may change its behavior. The working  code you took cannot be blamed for any code you added to it afterwards. You need to understand at least some basic things about the specific programming language and execution environment. In the case of XSLT this is called "XSLT processing model".

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, would you mind elaborating on `node()[not(self::*)]` here? Matches any node without children, i.e. empty elements and comments and… ?

Comment: @Jens, `node()[not(self::*)]` matches any node that is not an element: text, attribute, comment, PI, root, and namespace

Answer (score 3):

> Its working only if i include the above templates if i add some other templates other than the above one then the translation is not at all working .None of the template getting executed.

Probably you are missing the declaration of the namespace for the `book` element. Example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:b="http://www.books.com/SRK"
    exclude-result-prefixes="b">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

        <!-- @dimitre's answer templates -->

    <xsl:template match="b:name">
          <!-- your template for name -->
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Moreover, make sure to use `local-name()` function to get the name of an element without the related namespace.

---

**Example**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:b="http://www.books.com/SRK"
    exclude-result-prefixes="b">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>


    <xsl:template match="b:input">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="b:name"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="b:name">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
            <lhs>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::b:lhs/b:evaluate"/>
            </lhs>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="b:evaluate">
        Something to evaluate...    
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<input>
<name>English</name>
<lhs>
        Something to evaluate...    
    </lhs>
</input>
```

---

**Second Example**

You can create a separate transform called **local-identity.xsl** containing @Dimitre solution. Then you can import it in your transform. Because you have a namespace, to match elements you must change **all** your XPaths including the prefix you will declare in the transform, as in the following example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:brl="http://www.xyz.com/BRL"
    exclude-result-prefixes="brl"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:import href="local-identity.xsl"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


    <xsl:template match="/brl:rule">
     <!-- do your staff, select using brl prefix -->
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The idea to use exclude-result-prefixes="b" just helped me solve a related problem. Thanks!