# XSLT: Matching elements with namespaces not working

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, match, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to convert a database of XML song lyrics into HTML with XSLT. My XML begins like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<song xmlns="http://openlyrics.info/namespace/2009/song" version="0.8" createdIn="OpenLP      2.0.1" modifiedIn="OpenLP 2.0.1" modifiedDate="2012-03-14T02:21:52">
  <properties>
    <titles>
      <title>Amazing Grace</title>
    </titles>
    <authors>
      <author>John Newton</author>
    </authors>
  </properties>
  <lyrics>
    <verse name="v1">
      <lines>Amazing grace, how sweet the sound<br/>That saved a wretch like me<br/>I once was lost, but now am found<br/>Was blind but now I see</lines>
```

I know from other posts that I need to add the above namespace into my XSLT. I tried, and my XSLT looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:lyrics="http://openlyrics.info/namespace/2009/song">

<xsl:template match="lyrics:song">
  <h3><xsl:value-of select="properties/titles/title"/></h3>
  <h4><xsl:value-of select="properties/authors/author"/></h4>
  <xsl:for-each select="lyrics/verse">
  <xsl:copy-of select="lines" /><br /><br />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unfortunately, this code still isn't working. My XSLT only works when I eliminate the xmlns entry in my XML and match "song" directly. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong in regards to the xmlns namespace that I titled "lyrics?" I'm very new at XML/XSLT. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the **namespace prefix** "lyrics" at any element name which belong to the **namespaces** "`http://openlyrics.info/namespace/2009/song`". And this are all element names because it is the default namespace. Try somenthing like this (not tested):

```
<xsl:template match="lyrics:song">
  <h3><xsl:value-of select="lyrics:properties/lyrics:titles/lyrics:title"/></h3>
  <h4><xsl:value-of select="lyrics:properties/lyrics:authors/lyrics:author"/></h4>
  <xsl:for-each select="lyrics:lyrics/lyrics:verse">
  <xsl:copy-of select="lyrics:lines" /><br /><br />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try later. The namespace information is irrelevant to me, so is there any way using XSLT to eliminate the xmlns information in the <song> tag at the beginning of the XML?

Comment: The easiest way to remove the namespace declaration would be to use an editor. Do to this with xlst have a look for example to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6253642/2115381